# Add (insert) new columns to an existing file with different shape Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 5 files dataframe, which are each files contains with different shape on pandas.

1. 1st file contains of 3968 rows x 7 columns (Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume)
2. 2nd file contains of 3774 rows x 7 columns (Date1,Open1,High1,Low1,Close1,Adj Close1,Volume1)
3. 3rd file contains of 58 rows x 3 columns (No, Date, Rate)
4. 4th file contains of 192 rows x 3 columns (No1, Date1, Rates1)
5. 5th file contains of 1850 rows x 3 columns (No2, Date2,Rate2)

My Output will :

3968 rows x 16 columns

(Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume, Open1,High1,Low1,Close1,Adj Close1,Volume1, Rate, Rates1, Rates2)

How to append/insert the new columns on 1st file from 2nd - 5th files with diffent shapes?
is there any technique to match the different shapes?

I put my code :

```
df = pd.read_csv('^JKLQ45.csv') # 1st file
files = [file for file in os.listdir('./Raw Data')] #i put all the files
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    current_data = pd.read_csv('./Raw Data'+"/"+file)
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data, current_data])
    
all_data.to_csv("all_data_copy.csv", index=False)
```

the output are 9842 rows × 14 columns, but i want the shape will be 3968 rows x 16 columns

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this code inside the loop?

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

Comment: How to reduce the NaN values?

Comment: What do you want to replace NaN with?

Comment: i want to replace NaN with mean or median value, I had try but still got NaN values : all_data_fillna = all_data.fillna(all_data.mean(), inplace=True)
all_data.fillna

Comment: Can you post an example data frame?